# MS ACCESS 2007 - Deleting a specific record using an unbound value

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a subfrom 'Crew' with 3 field text boxes inside of that named CrewName, KitNumber, and ActionDate.  This form gets populated with data from a button.  What I want to do is have a user enter a number, say "111111" in this unbound text field called 'ClearEntry' outside of the Crew subform.  I then have a command button under that named 'ClearSelected' that, when clicked, will clear the corresponding record in my Crew subform.  So basically I want to enter text in this unbound, hit the button, and have that number correspond with the same number in the Crew Subform, and delete the record in that form.  My code I have now for the command button is below.

```
Private Sub ClearSelected_Click()
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL = "DELETE FROM Crew WHERE KitNumber = '" & Me.ClearEntry & "'"
Crew.Form.Requery
End Sub
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Is your code doing what you want?  If not, what happens when you change `SetWarnings` from off to on?  (`DoCmd.SetWarnings True`)

Comment: @HansUp, My code is not doing what I want.  Changing the SetWarnings just lets me know when I chose to delete a record.  The problem I get when hitting the command button is saying I have an "Argument not optional" and it highlights .ClearEntry in the debugger

Comment: That's good information, thanks.  That could happen if the form module includes a procedure (subroutine or function) which is also named `ClearEntry`.  Change the name of the text box to `txtClearEntry` and revise the `RunSQL` to match --- `Me.txtClearEntry`.  Now what happens (with `SetWarnings` still `True`)?

Comment: If you have two form objects named `Crew`, you are likely to run into problems.  Your query indicates a table with that name, and you say there is a form with that name.

Comment: I admire the recommendation from HansUp, but still want to toss in a bit of generic problem-solving advice:  Make this query run as a simple query, no VBA.  Once you are assured you can do that, step up to the VBA implementation and trouble-shoot at that level.

Comment: I changed the SetWarnings to true now.  But I still get the error that I had before.  I changed the names of the button to 'ClearKitSelected' and the unbound text to 'txtClearKitEntry' and still get that same problem as before.  The debugger pops up saying "Compile error: Argument not optional" and then I hit OK and the Private Sub function is highlighted in yellow while the .txtClearKitEntry is still highlighted until I click around

Comment: @HansUp, do you have a site that you would prefer?  Like dropbox or something else?

Comment: "crew" is your subform ? what is the table contains data source about CrewName, KitNumber, and ActionDate ? Can you try : 1. Refresh your database after deleting . 2. Change to Me.Crew.Form.Requery . But I still think that your error might come from somewhere else, if you can share me the file also I can debug it.

Comment: @HansUp, Here is the [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12158513/Kits.accdb) via dropbox. I wrote some notes next to the button and unbound where I need help on. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *"argument not optional"* compile error is caused by the `=` sign after `DoCmd.RunSQL`.  Get rid of it:

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM Crew WHERE KitNumber = '" & Me.txtClearKitEntry& "'"
```

Then you will get an error complaining about *"type mismatch in criteria"* because `Crew.KitNumber` is numeric not text.  So do not add the single quotes around `Me.txtClearKitEntry`.

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM Crew WHERE KitNumber = " & Me.txtClearKitEntry
```

However I'll suggest this approach instead of `DoCmd.RunSQL`.  When you're not using `RunSQL`, you won't be motivated to turn `SetWarnings` off (`False`).

```vb
Private Sub ClearKitSelected_Click()
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim strSql As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    strSql = "DELETE FROM Crew WHERE KitNumber = " & Me.txtClearKitEntry
    CurrentDb.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError
    Me.Crew.Requery

ExitHere:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    strMsg = "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description _
        & ") in procedure ClearKitSelected_Click of Form_Search"
    MsgBox strMsg
    GoTo ExitHere
End Sub
```

Comment: You're welcome, Patrick.  Sorry it took me so long to notice the `=` after `RunSQL`;  I don't use `RunSQL`.  I decided to give you a better version of `ClearKitSelected_Click`.  Regards, H.

Answer (score 0):

This was how I finally was able to get it to work correctly:

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click()
Dim strMsg As String
Dim strSql As String

If Me.Dirty Then
Me.Dirty = False
End If
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Const MESSAGETEXT = "Are you sure you wish to delete the current record?"
 If MsgBox(MESSAGETEXT, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Confirm") = vbNo Then
     Cancel = True
 End If
 strSql = "DELETE FROM Item WHERE ID = " & Me.txtID2
 CurrentDb.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError

 MsgBox "The Item list has been updated"
 Clear
 List40.Requery

 ExitHere:
 On Error GoTo 0
 Exit Sub

 ErrorHandler:
 strMsg = "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description _
     & ") in procedure Delete of Items"
 MsgBox strMsg
 GoTo ExitHere

 End Sub
```